# How Do I Obtain Exposed Variables From CodeBuild In The CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

AWS notes there are a variety of [Code Build Environment Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) available to use.

**Problem:** I am trying to access the environment variables, to dynamically name stacks. However, within the CDK code, I am not sure where to write such variables and assign them values.

**Current Code:**

```
this.codePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, `${environment}-${appName}-`, {
  pipelineName: `${environment}-${appName}-`,
  selfMutation: true,
  crossAccountKeys: false,
  role: this.codePipelineRole,
  synth: new ShellStep("Deployment", {
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(this.codeRepository, environment, {
      codeBuildCloneOutput: true,
    }),
    installCommands: ["npm i -g npm@latest"],
    commands: [
      "cd backend",
      "npm ci",
      "npm run build",
      "cdk synth",
    ],
    primaryOutputDirectory: "backend/cdk.out",
  })
});
```

Environment variable I wish to use `CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION` .

Note: I have tried writing `env: { ["CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION"] : branchName },` in the synth `ShellStep` props, but obtained the error: `No user environment variables can start with CODEBUILD_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables such as `CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION` are available in the node environment.

This means you could access them in your CDK code with `process.env.CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION`.